# How to use VIRTUAL columns with TS in Sequelize?

Tags: javascript, typescript, sequelize.js, virtual-column

I have a class `Pin` that has the basic structure:

```
export default class Pin
  extends Model<InferAttributes<Pin>, InferCreationAttributes<Pin>>
{
  declare pinID: CreationOptional<IDType>
  declare startingDate: Date
  declare endingDate: Date | undefined
  declare active: boolean
}
```

and the initialization:

```
Pin.init(
    {
      pinID: {
        type: DataTypes.INTEGER.UNSIGNED,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
      },
      startingDate: { type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: false },
      endingDate: { type: DataTypes.DATEONLY, allowNull: true },
      active: {
        type: DataTypes.VIRTUAL(DataTypes.BOOLEAN, [
          'startingDate',
          'endingDate',
        ]),
        set(value) {
          throw new Error('Cannot set VIRTUAL column `active`')
        },
        get() {
          return (
            this.startingDate > new Date() &&
            (!this.endingDate || this.endingDate < new Date())
          )
        }
      }
    }
)
```

But this approach with `declare active: boolean` gives me (understandably) the error:

```
Type 'PinData' is not assignable to type 'Omit<InferCreationAttributes<Pin, { omit: never; }>, NullishPropertiesOf<InferCreationAttributes<Pin, { omit: never; }>>>'.
    Types of property 'active' are incompatible.
      Type 'boolean | undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
        Type 'undefined' is not assignable to type 'boolean'.
```

But I cannot declare `active` as `NonAttribute`, otherwise I could not add it as a virtual column (`Object literal may only specify known properties, and 'active' does not exist in type 'ModelAttributes<Pin, Optional<InferAttributes<Pin, { omit: never; }>>>'.`) Is there another utility-type provided by Sequelize to enable TS with virtual fields, or how can I fix this problem?